# PHP - MYSQL Query multiple values from an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I want to run an insert query in a loop until all the elements from an array pass.

Ex:

```
$signs = array("aries", "taurus", "gemini", "cancer", "leo", "virgo", "libra", "scorpio", "sagittarius", "capricorn", "aquarius", "pisces");


$config = array('sign' => 'aries',
                'type' => 'daily',
                'date' => date('Y-m-d'),);


$content = $horoscope->get_daily_horoscope($config);
$update = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `horoscope` (`zodiacal_sign`, `last_updated`, `content`) values (%s,%s,%s)", $config['sign'], $config['date'], $content);
$db->query($update);
```

I don't know how to run this query until all of `$signs` replaces `$config['sign']` and the query runs all the 12 times in a loop.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: The question is not so clear maybe you could try `array_pop` in a `for` loop if i have understood some of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this..

```
$signs = array("aries", "taurus", "gemini", "cancer", "leo", "virgo", "libra", "scorpio",     "sagittarius", "capricorn", "aquarius", "pisces");

foreach($signs as $s){


    $config = array('sign' => $s,
            'type' => 'daily',
            'date' => date('Y-m-d'),);


    $content = $horoscope->get_daily_horoscope($config);
    $update = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `horoscope` (`zodiacal_sign`, `last_updated`, `content`) values (%s,%s,%s)", $config['sign'], $config['date'], $content);
    $db->query($update);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. well... almost. max_execution_time is set to 30 and the script tages longer. do you think there is a way to split `$signs` in two and run the two queries one by one (first 6 signs and next the last 6 of them)?

Comment: yes you can. just split the $signs to two and do two foreach() statement.